# how can I adjust the ToolBarTray orientation dynamically?

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I am trying to set ToolBarTray orientation dynamically, so that I can create an auto-adjusted toolbar, same as Microsoft Office 2003.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't told us what actually should trigger the change of the orientation. But suppose it depends on the place where the tray is docked in a `DockPanel`, you could bind to the `DockPanel.Dock` attached property:

```
<ToolBarTray Orientation={Binding (DockPanel.Dock), Converter={StaticResource myDockToOrientationConverter}} />
```

`myDockToOrientationConverter` is a `IValueConverter` you will have to write that converts `Dock.Left` and `Dock.Right` to `Orientation.Vertical` and `Dock.Top` and `Dock.Bottom` to `Orientation.Horizontal`.